# Use of PIL in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, python-imaging-library

I want to use PIL library in Visual Studio. I have installed PIL 1.1.7 for Python 2.7 but I am facing error when I am running through Visual Studio 2013.

How do I get my output?

[image]

Comment: What error? ALso manby dont use PIL. PIL is discontinued. Use Pillow.

Comment: Can you kindly add the actual error to the question?

Comment: Pillow documentation: pillow.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Hi Mikko..I have attached snapshot of the error that is displaying...Also I wanted to run the codes that are there in http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm#enhancement to understand more how does they work...please help me with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct path to the image in the line `im = Image.open("bridge.jpg")`.

Either make sure bridge.jpg is in the correct directory, or include the full absolute or relative path to it.